# Calculations in pstricks swallows the spaces after a command

Tags: xetex, pstricks, counters, ps

The following MWE works fine when plotting a square using pstricks with xelatex.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pstricks}
 \begin{document}
   \def\x{0 } % Notice that there MUST be a white space after 0
   \psframe(\x, 1)(!1 \x add 1 1 add)
 \end{document}
```

The problems is, when I try to make the `\psframe` in a whiledo loop with a counter, the space after a command is swallowed. Look at the following MWE:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pstricks}
 \newcounter{Y}
 \setcounter{Y}{1}
 \begin{document}
   \def\x{0 }
   \def\Y{\theY  }
   \psframe(\x, \Y)(!1 \x add 1 \Y add)
 \end{document}
```

When compile with the command `xelatex test` where test.tex is the name of the source file, it throws the following error:

```
 Using PSTricks configuration for XeTeX+xdvipdfmx
 ))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex))
 (./test.aux) [1] (./test.aux)Error: /undefined in 1add
 Operand stack:
    --nostringval--   0.0   true   0.0   28.4527   1   1
```

Looks like after expanding \Y in `\psframe`, the second coordinate becomes `(!1 0 add 1 1add)` where the white space between the last `1` and `add` is swallowed.

How can the value of a counter be used in the coordinate calculations in pstricks? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\psframe(\x, \Y)(!1 \x\space add 1 \Y\space add}
```

Otherwise the spaces get lost